# Can I get JSON from url?

Tags: android, json, parsing

Good day, I have this link: http://satiksme.daugavpils.lv/ru-tramvajs-nr-1-butlerova-iela-stacija

Please select to the source code view or use :

`view-source:http://satiksme.daugavpils.lv/ru-tramvajs-nr-1-butlerova-iela-stacija`

If you use `CTRL + F` and put `var data =` you can find the `JSON` object.

The question is: Can I parse that using Volley, or it isn't `JSON` at all? If no, How can I parse that to my app (SQLite)? (using volley, or maybe GSON)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pdegand59 post was g8, but here is demo if you still struggle with this problem.

```
    private static TextView text;
    Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("var data = (.*)");
    String url="http://satiksme.daugavpils.lv/ru-tramvajs-nr-1-butlerova-iela-stacija";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    //here you are downloading your page into a response string
                    public void onResponse(String response) { 
                        //regexp search for data
                        Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(response); 

                        if (m.find()) {
                            String extracted = m.group(1).trim();
                            try {
                                //HERE is Json obj you are looking for
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(extracted); 
                                int spacesToIndentEachLevel = 2;
                                text.setText(obj.toString(spacesToIndentEachLevel));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                text.setText("error");
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

You will also need `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'` or something simmilar for your Volley in build.gradle.

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` in your manifest.

Comment: Fine example. However, you'd try to do the matching and unserialization into a separate thread. For such case, the String dowloaded by Volley will be huge and matching on such big string can take some times. Your code is a good start for the OP to optimize :)

Comment: @pdegand59 good point. And i 100% support the idea from your post to [implement a custom request](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Volley & GSON but you have to do some work :

1. Download your page in plain text format with Volley (into a String)
2. In the entire result, look for the string `var data =` to get the correct line number.
3. Extract this line, remove the `var data =` part
4. Use GSON to deserialize this extracted JSON

You might want to [implement a custom request](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html) that does all the heavy work in the `parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)` method. This will ensure that all the long tasks will be executed off the main thread and won't freeze your app.

Comment: How can I download page into a String? Try to search it, but using Volley nothing found. Share with code please